# Finding values of vector that occur within range of another vector's values

Tags: r

I have two sequences. They are times in seconds.  I wish to know which values in sequence b occur within 10s of any value in sequence a.

```
seqa = c(4.53333333333333, 7.43333333333334, 9.03333333333333, 20.6166666666667, 
20.6333333333333, 42.5666666666667, 48.3166666666667, 48.8, 49.75, 
55.1, 56.7833333333333, 59.3833333333333, 110.15, 113.95, 114.6)

seqb = c(18.3833333333333, 18.3833333333333, 63.8833333333333, 72.3166666666667, 
76.7166666666667, 85.2166666666667, 91.25, 91.3666666666667, 
96.2833333333333)
```

I have done this using two `for` loops.  Going through each element of `seqb` and testing if it occurs at a time greater than each value of `seqa` but within a 10 second limit.

```
matX <- matrix(nrow=length(seqa), ncol=length(seqb))

for(j in seq_along(seqb)){
  for(i in seq_along(seqa)){
    test1 <- seqb[j]>=seqa[i]
    test2 <- seqb[j]<=seqa[i]+10
    matX[i,j] <- sum(test1 + test2)
  }
}
matX
```

I'm storing the results in a matrix. You can see the values of 2 in columns 1, 2 and 3.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
 [3,]    2    2    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
 [4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
 [5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
 [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
 [7,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
 [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
 [9,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[10,]    1    1    2    1    1    1    1    1    1
[11,]    1    1    2    1    1    1    1    1    1
[12,]    1    1    2    1    1    1    1    1    1
[13,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[14,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
[15,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1

out <- apply(matX, 2, function(x) any(x>=2))    
seqb[out]

# [1] 18.38333 18.38333 63.88333
```

These values are those that occur within 10s of at least one value in `seqa`.  (The first two occur within 10s of 9.03333, the third value 63.8333 occurs within 10s of three values of seqa (55.1, 56.78333, 59.38333).

I am trying to speed this up as I will be doing some randomizations of sequences of about 2000 elements.   Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two base options

```
seqa = c(4.53333333333333, 7.43333333333334, 9.03333333333333, 20.6166666666667, 
         20.6333333333333, 42.5666666666667, 48.3166666666667, 48.8, 49.75, 
         55.1, 56.7833333333333, 59.3833333333333, 110.15, 113.95, 114.6)

seqb = c(18.3833333333333, 18.3833333333333, 63.8833333333333, 72.3166666666667, 
         76.7166666666667, 85.2166666666667, 91.25, 91.3666666666667, 
         96.2833333333333)


## via alexis_laz
a <- function() seqb[seqa[findInterval(seqb, seqa)] + 10 >= seqb]
# [1] 18.38333 18.38333 63.88333


## f
(function() {
  la <- length(seqa)
  lb <- length(seqb)
  rr <- rep(seqb, each = la)
  m <- matrix(rep(seqa, length(seqb)) - rr, la)
  +(m < 0 & abs(m) <= 10)
})()

## g
o <- outer(seqa, seqb, `-`)
x <- +(o < 0 & abs(o) <= 10)

`dimnames<-`(x, list(round(seqa, 2), round(seqb, 2)))

#        18.38 18.38 63.88 72.32 76.72 85.22 91.25 91.37 96.28
# 4.53       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 7.43       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 9.03       1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 20.62      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 20.63      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 42.57      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 48.32      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 48.8       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 49.75      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 55.1       0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 56.78      0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 59.38      0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 110.15     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 113.95     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# 114.6      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Some benches on my crummy hardware

```
library('microbenchmark')
seqa <- rep(seqa, 100)
seqb <- rep(seqb, 100)
microbenchmark(f(), g(), baseR(), DT(), unit = 'relative')
# Unit: relative
#      expr        min         lq       mean    median         uq       max neval  cld
#       f()   525.3178  374.23871  402.51609  386.4717  372.50657  496.6496   100   c 
#       g()   293.2158  223.21560  247.40211  241.3430  225.80202  443.5323   100  bc 
#   baseR() 13268.9357 9357.70517 8895.30834 9111.6828 8466.15623 6702.1735   100    d
#      DT()   136.1109   93.61985   96.88054   96.0771   95.03329  100.5602   100 ab  
#       a()     1.0000    1.00000    1.00000    1.0000    1.00000    1.0000   100 a
```

Comment: If "seqa" is sorted as it seems and if the intermediate matrix is not needed, another way -unless I'm missing something that in the example is not obvious- could be `seqb[seqa[findInterval(seqb, seqa)] + 10 >= seqb]` to avoid comparing everything to everything.

Comment: @alexis_laz clever! and super duper fastest by far

Comment: @alexis_laz should this work for sequences of all different lengths >1 - trying it for some other sequence pairs of varying lengths, I get this message:  `Warning message:
In seqa[findInterval(seqb, seqa)] + dt >= seqb :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Comment: @jalapic is the min of seqa < min seqb?, if not, findinterval will give you some 0s

Comment: @rawr it is in the example, but not always. The algorithm should be able to work interchangeably on two sequences (with obviously different outputs). i.e.  `fun1(seqa,seqb)` and `fun1(seqb,seqa)` should return values of the second sequence within 10s of the first sequence.

Comment: If you want to compare `a()` to the other solutions, shouldn't it construct the matrix, as well.

Comment: @Jalapic : as rawr showed there are some edgecases; with a bit of control flow though, and using workarounds like `all.inside = TRUE`, or `findInterval(x, c(-Inf, vec, Inf))` many fixes seem to be easily made

Comment: @jalapic : Unless, I've missed something a workaround like `ff = function(x, y, n = 10) { ints = findInterval(x, y); wh = which(ints > 0); ints = ints[wh]; x = x[wh]; x[y[ints] + n >= x] }` seems valid? `ff(seqa, seqb); ff(seqb, seqa)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `foverlaps` function from the `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)

b <- data.table(seqb)
a <- data.table(seqa)
a[, end := seqa + 10]
setkey(a)
b[, end := seqb]

inds <- foverlaps(b, a,
                  by.x=c("seqb","end"), 
                  type="within",
                  mult="all",
                  which=TRUE # you can use nomatch=0L, but it doesn't change the final matrix
                 )
 #   xid yid
 #1:   1   3
 #2:   2   3
 #3:   3  10
 #4:   3  11
 #5:   3  12
 #6:   4  NA
 #7:   5  NA
 #8:   6  NA
 #9:   7  NA
#10:   8  NA
#11:   9  NA
```

These indices can now be used to create the matrix you want.

```
mat <- matrix(1, nrow=length(seqa), ncol=length(seqb))
mat[cbind(inds$yid, inds$xid)] <- 2
```

Here it is in a function with `seqa` and `seqb` hardcode:

```
DT <- function(){
    b <- data.table(seqb)
    a <- data.table(seqa)
    a[, end := seqa + 10]
    setkey(a)
    b[, end := seqb]

    inds <- foverlaps(b, a,
                      by.x=c("seqb","end"), 
                      type="within",
                      mult="all",
                      which=TRUE 
                     )

    mat <- matrix(1, nrow=length(seqa), ncol=length(seqb))
    mat[cbind(inds$yid, inds$xid)] <- 2
    mat
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
seqa = c(4.53333333333333, 7.43333333333334, 9.03333333333333, 20.6166666666667, 20.6333333333333, 42.5666666666667, 48.3166666666667, 48.8, 49.75, 55.1, 56.7833333333333, 59.3833333333333, 110.15, 113.95, 114.6)

seqb = c(18.3833333333333, 18.3833333333333, 63.8833333333333, 2.3166666666667, 76.7166666666667, 85.2166666666667, 91.25, 91.3666666666667, 96.2833333333333)
```

Data read in above. Below, I show my approach, and that of @jota. Note that this is a bit of a silly comparison, since the data are so small. The `data.table` solution is almost certainly way faster on larger data.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)

DT <- function(){
   b <- data.table(seqb)
   a <- data.table(seqa)
   a[, end := seqa + 10]
   setkey(a)
   b[, end := seqb]

   inds <- foverlaps(b, a,
                     by.x=c("seqb","end"), 
                     type="within",
                     mult="all",
                     which=TRUE 
                    )

   mat <- matrix(1, nrow=length(seqa), ncol=length(seqb))
   mat[cbind(inds$yid, inds$xid)] <- 2
   mat
}



baseR <- function(){
    out <- matrix(NA, ncol=length(seqb), nrow=length(seqa));
    for(i in 1:length(seqa)){
        out[i,] <- sapply(seqb, function(x){seqa[i] -10 < x  & x < seqa[i] +10})
    }
    out
}


microbenchmark(
    baseR(), DT()
)
```

And the results for the microbenchmark (for fun).

```
Unit: microseconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq      max neval
 baseR()  703.382  750.129  786.283  770.867  788.3085 1905.357   100
    DT() 7289.433 7415.906 7631.574 7503.236 7575.7345 8794.439   100
```

Comment: If you change your function inside of `sapply` to `seqa[i] < x  & x < seqa[i] +10`, you'll match the output listed by jalapic.  FYI, I changed my data.table answer a little, so the one you have posted as `datTable()` is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IRanges` package.

```
library(IRanges)

a.ir <- IRanges(round(seqa, 4)*1e4, round(seqa, 4)*1e4+10*1e4)
b.ir <- IRanges(round(seqb, 4)*1e4, round(seqb, 4)*1e4)

findOverlaps(b.ir, a.ir)
# Hits of length 5
# queryLength: 9
# subjectLength: 15
#   queryHits subjectHits 
#    <integer>   <integer> 
# 1         1           3 
# 2         2           3 
# 3         3          10 
# 4         3          11 
# 5         3          12 

seqb[unique(queryHits(findOverlaps(b.ir, a.ir)))]
# [1] 18.38333 18.38333 63.88333
```

Comment: Instead of `findOverlaps` you could use directly `seqb[countOverlaps(b.ir, a.ir) > 0]`; it's also, probably, faster. But, to be honest, I feel it's a bit error-prone to arbitrarily round floating point values and do computations on behalf of them?

Comment: `countOverlaps` also works. As IRanges only accept integers, you have to change these values to integers. It should be okay for the OP.